# Make a list tile button turn grey when clicked

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I make individual buttons turn grey when I click on approve?
The screenshot is below

[image: Screenshot]

Below is the List Tile widget code

```
Widget pendingList({
  required String title,
  required String subtitle,
  required String leading,
  onTap,
}) {
  return Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 6,
        child: Card(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      'therul'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: BtnFnt2,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
            subtitle: Text(
              subtitle,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: littleTexts,
              ),
            ),
            
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 2,
        child: Bounce(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
          onPressed: onTap,
          child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      color: appOrange,
      child: Text(
        'Approve',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        ),
      ),
    ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

How can I make individual buttons turn grey when I click on approve?
Any idea will be appreciated. Kindly refer to the screenshot and assist if you can.

Comment: please, if you don't understand the question kindly say so instead of giving a negative vote. I have a very long code and I don't see it helpful to paste everything. I pasted what is related to the question am asking.

Answer (score 2):

One way, is to make the card into a stateful widget, like (simplified)

```
class ColorCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const ColorCard({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ColorCard> createState() => _ColorCardState();
}

class _ColorCardState extends State<ColorCard> {
  Color col = Colors.white;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: col,
      child: ListTile(
        title: const Text('title'),
        subtitle: const Text('subtitle'),
        trailing: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() => col = Colors.grey);
          },
          child: const Text('click'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Alternatively the color could be based on a value stored in an object that `extends` or 'mixin'-s [ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html) if you want more comprehensive integration.

Comment: Thanks @Andre for your answer, but it doesn't really solve the issue. I tried it and it marked all cards at once. What I want is mark the card when the 'approve' next to it is clicked just like you have when clicking the follow button on Instagram or Twitter